# Bases de datos relacional: problema al introducir datos

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando crear una base de datos dónde dos tablas tienen una relación con una tabla intermedia.

La idea es sencilla; una tabla almacena los registros de los usuarios, sus contraseñas, emails etc, mientras que la otra almacene niveles. (Los niveles pertenecen a una especie de videojuego dónde el usuario registrado puede seleccionar que nivel desea jugar, y en la tabla intermediaria se hace una consulta cuándo lo haya pasado.) `niveles` almacena atributos como el nivel, la descripción del nivel y los puntos obtenidos tras pasar el nivel.

De modo que tenemos la tabla `usuarios`, la tabla `niveles` y la tabla `niveles_pasados`.

`niveles_pasados` almacena únicamente la información del usuario, el nivel pasado, y los puntos obtenidos por pasarlo.

Lo que pretendo es, que cada vez que el usuario consiga pasar un nivel, realizar un `insert into` dentro de `niveles_pasados`, almacenando la información del usuario que lo pasó, el nivel que pasó, y los puntos que ganó.

He intentado crear las tablas y relacionarlas de la mañera siguiente pero al introducir datos en la tabla `niveles_pasados` me devuelve el siguiente error.

[image: Relaciones:]

[image: Error generado:]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ha explicado bastante bien su requerimiento y se nota que ha hecho un esfuerzo para facilitarnos ayudarle. Sin embargo tiene más que una pregunta; y creo sería mejor tener el foco en la pregunta principal. Las otras preguntas podría ponerlas aparte en este sitio, es mi recomendación.

Comment: Hay varios errores claros de planteamiento en tu diseño. La columna `Usuario` que tienes en la tabla `niveles_pasados` no sirve de nada, sólo crea duplicidad de datos. En esa relación tú conoces el usuario por el `ID`. Lo mismo ocurre con la columna `puntos` que tienes en la tabla `niveles` (a no ser que eso represente los puntos necesarios para acceder a ese nivel). En cuanto al error, tú no puedes actualizar usando un valor que no existe en las tablas relacionadas, porque eso violaría la integridad referencial.

Comment: aquí esta la [sala de chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75428/base-de-datos-mysql).

Comment: Sharki aún así, es un error de diseño. Has de saber que cuando se trabaja con tablas relacionadas, tú puedes unir varias tablas mediante `JOIN`. En este caso entre las tablas `usuarios` y `niveles_pasados`, obteniendo el nombre de usuario de **su tabla**. Precisamente para eso existen las bases de datos relacionales: **para no tener datos redundantes** ... para eso y para muchas cosas más. Imagínate bases de datos que manejan millones y millones de registros, sin son 10,000 millones de usuarios `x  2= 20,000 millones`. Y  no te digo nada de controlar errores de escritura, el rendimiento, etc.

Comment: @SharkiAragon Yo también creo que su diseño es mejorable. Tengo otra pregunta. Como puede un usuario pasar un nivel 3 con más puntos que otro usuario quién también pasa un nivel 3 ? Creo que necesite especificar más los requerimientos porque impacta al diseño en mi opinión.

Comment: @Elyasin Un usuario puede empezar por el nivel que quiera, ya que están todos accesibles, pero los niveles dan diferente puntuación, es por ello que un usuario puede hacer el mismo nivel que otro con diferente puntuación si anteriormente ya hizo otros niveles dónde se le recompensó más que al otro usuario.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75522/discussion-on-question-by-sharki-aragon-bases-de-datos-relacional-problema-al-i).

Answer (score 3):

1) Para realizar un INSERT en **niveles_pasados** primero debes asegurarte que existan los registros referenciados en la tabla **usuarios** y en la tabla **niveles**.

Es decir:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(0, "usuario1","password1","email@aaa.com");
INSERT INTO niveles VALUES(1, "Nivel 1", 100);
INSERT INTO niveles_pasados VALUES(0, "usuario1",1, 105);
```

De esta manera el registro en "niveles_pasados" referencia el usuario "usuario1" y el nivel 1

Si el registro "usuario1" no existe, no se va cumple la clave foranea.
Si el registro "Nivel 1" no existe, tampoco se cumple la clave.

2) Si cada usuario tiene "errores" entonces porque no agregar un campo mas a la tabla "usuarios"?

3) La consulta que te permite conocer la suma de puntos del usuario "usuario1"

```
SELECT SUM(Puntos) FROM usuarios u, niveles_pasados n WHERE u.USER = n.Usuario AND u.USER = "usuario1"
```